# Set parameter as element id then change its value in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a code here:

```
$.each(localStorage, function(key, value){
    if (key.indexOf('(cache)') > -1) {
      var id = key.replace("(cache)", "");
      id = '#' + id;
      $(id).val(value);
    } 
});
```

My target is to update the value of the `specific id` but it gives an error of `unkown expression (expected id here)`

and also here is the image of the error

[image]

Comment: `id = '#' + id;$(id).val(value);` needs to be `$('#' + id).val(value);` . Also what is the value of `id`? And this id belongs to a text-box input or something else?

Comment: What do the localStorage items look like? Runs fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/krv6uv7L/

Comment: sir this is the id looks like `05/03/2018 15:39:51JxM8tX8K`

Comment: all of the id in the localstorage belong to a textbox

Comment: i added some image

Comment: is this your `id`-> `05/03/2018 15:39:51JxM8tX8K`??????

Comment: yes thats my id

Comment: That's an invalid ID

Comment: uhuum that would become a problem. thats the id i set for my elements :(

Comment: Put `@` before usernames (eg `@CertainPerformance`) to ping people, otherwise they'll often not see that you've replied to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly recommended to convert `id` properly (don't use dates and spaces). But if you can't then below is a solution

Working snippet:-

```js
myval = 1;
id= '05/03/2018 15:39:51JxM8tX8K';
$('[id="'+id+'"]').val(myval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="05/03/2018 15:39:51JxM8tX8K"><br>
<input type="text" id="05/03/2018 15:39:51JxM8tX8KDKHFCK">
```

Note:-I am not fully sure that it will work for you perfectly or not. Test it and let me know

Comment: It works sir tysm

Comment: @NardongBagsik  glad to help you :):)